# How to use unique constraint in spring boot for a many to many relationship table?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a many to many relationship between two tables. The two tables are Player and Games. A Player may have many Games and a Game can be played by many Players.
I have created a many-to-many relationship like so.

Player.java

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "listOfPlayers")
private List<Game> listOfGames;
```

Game.java

```
@Column(unique = true)
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "player_game",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
)
private List<Player> listOfPlayers;
```

Please note `unique` constraint in my game table. I am trying to make sure that when I insert `player` into `listOfPlayers` List, each player object is unique so that If I try to insert a duplicate player object in my controller by doing `game.addPlayersToGame(player)` it should handle the exception and throw an error. But at the moment with the above code, duplicate player objects get saved on my database.

Comment: One rule of thumb is Many-To-Many relationship needs to have a third table for mapping. In that table you can enforce your desired unique constraint. For example `map_player_game (pk id, fk player_id, fk game_id)`

Comment: @MohammedAtif, Currently my join table is `player_game` and it has no primary key as shown above. I still do not understand how I can enforce unique constraint so that each player object in the lisOfPlayers is unique and no duplicate data is inserted. Should I make the primary of the join table combination of `game_id` and `player_id`?

Comment: You don't need to add primary key, you can directly add composite key in your join table. And then in your models use Set instead of List

Comment: @MohammedAtif, Thank you but why change Set instead of List. Is that because a Set does not allow duplicate item? If that is the case then it should work. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Since they are pojos, and if you don't implement equal and hashcode then duplicates are still possible. But as a coding practice Set represent unique and List represent duplicate. But actual change you have to do in the map table itself to avoid duplicate.